# Java: import my own package in a different folder

Tags: java

Here is the source code structure showing in Eclipse

```
ProjectName
  src
    (default package)
      Main.java

  test
    abc.java
```

Here is the source code

test/abc.java

```
package test;
public class abc {}
```

src/Main.java

```
import test.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main");
    }
}
```

import test.* cannot pass Eclipse compiler.

How to import package "test"?

Comment: How have you configured Eclipse in terms of source roots? It looks like you have a "root" source root, and `src` as a source root *inside* that - that's asking for trouble. Keep your source roots separate from each other.

Comment: Double checked, Eclipse has an option where to be source root. Now I selected "Use project folder as root for sources and class files", and the Main.java is under projectName without "src". Then "import test.*" passes compiler.

Comment: Yes, it would - but you probably still want to have two separate source roots... and I'd advise you to *always* use packages for anything that isn't immediate throwaway code.

Answer (score 0):

`test` is not a package - it's another source folder. In Eclipse (or any other IDE, for that matter), you should mark it as a test folder, and then use the classes without importing anything, as your code is in the default package.

Comment: "test" was created as "Package" by new -> package in Eclipse.

Comment: If it's supposed to be a package, it should be located under the `src` folder, not next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import files from another *source* folder, in eclipse.
After the project is built, files from all source folders are compiled in single build folder.
`Test` is folder for testing files.

---

### Bottom line :

1. You need **NOT** import    `test` folder.
2. Check the package name defined in class. Rename it to some other name and then try importing.
3. Don't create source folders as eclipse would create the source folder by itself depending on the package name defined in class